# Kotlin: Read Only access of Immutable Type to an Internal Variable of a Mutable Type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

While learning ViewModels in Android, a problem has arisen that feels like Kotlin was meant to solve. In the code below, we can see that MutableLiveData values are being use to edit values and indicators. However, we do not want these mutable values to be exposed to anything else, specifically members of an Android lifecycle. We DO want Android Lifecycle members to have access to read values but not set them. Therefore, the 3 exposed functions, displayed below, are of the LiveData<> immutable type.

**Is there an easier or more concise way to expose read only values that can be edited internally?** This seems like what Kotlin was made to avoid: boilerplate verbosity.

```
class HomeListViewModel: ViewModel(){
    //Private mutable data
    private val repositories = MutableLiveData<List<Repo>>()
    private val repoLoadError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()


    //Exposed uneditable LIveData
    fun getRepositories():LiveData<List<Repo>> = repositories
    fun getLoadError(): LiveData<Boolean> = repoLoadError
    fun getLoadingStatuses(): LiveData<Boolean> = loading

    init{...//Do some stuff to MutableLiveData<>

    }
}
```

A non-Android scenario that might be similar is:

```
class ImmutableAccessExample{

    private val theThingToBeEditedInternally = mutableListOf<String>()

    fun theThingToBeAccessedPublicly(): List<String> = theThingToBeEditedInternally

    init {
        theThingToBeEditedInternally.add(0, "something")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to avoid the verbosity. But, I've seen that before and it is usually declared as a property.

```
private val _repositories = MutableLiveData<List<Repo>>()
val repositories : LiveData<List<Repo>> 
    get() = _repositories
```

This is the convention, see [the doc here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#property-names) in **Names for backing properties**

> If a class has two properties which are conceptually the same but one is part of a public API and another is an implementation detail, use an underscore as the prefix for the name of the private property:

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, I still curious if you can avoid the verbosity

Comment: I'll post something in the Kotlin forums. My thought was that we could set the get() for the MutableData member "= this as Data"

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of [this post](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/exposing-a-mutable-member-as-immutable/6359/8):

```
class HomeListViewModel: ViewModel(){
    val repositories: LiveData<List<Repo>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        repositories as MutableLiveData
        ...//Do some stuff to repositories
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any elegant solution to this problem however this is how I handle it.

```
private val selectedPositionLiveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
fun getSelectedPosition() = selectedPositionLiveData as LiveData<Int>
```

The `View` observes via the public getter method and there's no need to define a second member in the `ViewModel`. I probably favour this approach due to my Java background with explicit getters but this seems to me to be as clean and concise as any of the other workarounds.

Answer (score -2):

val doesn't have a setter since it's readonly but if you want a var you can do this

```
var repositories = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    private set
var repoLoadError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private set
var loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private set
```

This will give you a private setter and a public getter

Comment: Since it is MutableLiveData, I can still perform operations on this dataset, despite not being able to call, for example, repositories.set(...). I could still call repositories.value = "...". I was hoping I could leave them as val, but make the get() of these return the immutable datatype of LiveData, as indicated currently by the functions

Comment: Mutable *object* not mutable *reference*. We need the same `MutableLiveData` object but change its property.